# Unidentified Uploading Error on Apache ,Plesk11 Ubuntu server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, file-upload, plesk

I am using uploader on my site. When i try to upload a file larger than 150MB it uploads 1% Then reverts back and again goes to some 1% and then Fails. I thought it could be uploader problem but, again i created single fileuploader than also same thing happened. I am using apache , and nginx as reverse proxy support On parallel plesk 11 on Ubuntu server 10.04

I checked Error log. I found this

Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden

I keep on getting this error when my .htaccess file is this

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]


ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

My php info details are this.

i have apc installed on the server

```
apc.max_file_size 1M


max_file_uploads 20
max_execution_time 0
post_max_size 200M
upload_max_filesize 450M
```

Comment: May this will help you http://www.virtualmin.com/node/17048

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary How can this error have relation with uploading error. I just found only this error in error log.

Comment: there may be some apache configuration problem! As if your file is being uploaded upto 1% then permission Issue can not be exisits!

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary the file upto 150MB can be uploaded without any error.

Comment: have you tried to set_time_limit(0); ?

Comment: also increase your  post_max_size more than max file size that you want.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Alright i will try this too. thanks :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17750/discussion-between-abhishek-gahlot-and-rohit-kumar-choudhary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use Fastcgid on plesk you need also add this to config:

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 471859200

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf
```

So Fastcgid see that file and not the php.ini for some values.

So, I think this is the problem if using Fastcgi.

Sorry for my bad english I try improve it, and I hope this help you ;)

Comment: Actually i have added this previously when i got problem . i was having error when uploading files, I added this, but now the problem is something else. Really if any one can help me,i can find out what the problem is. :(

Comment: So, you need see your error_log and fcgid error_log when you upload, then you can get more information.

User tail -f error_log when you uploading

The logs are on: /var/log and /var/www/vhost/domain.com/statiscs/logs